# What is the meaning of a >>= b?

Tags: c++, operators

I browsed through the internet and got to know that it is a compound assignment operator. But how does it work?

I used [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) link to get to know about the definition, but I couldn't find the exact implementation of this syntax.

Comment: shift a to the left b times. Equivalent to integer divide by 2**b.

Comment: Its `a=a>>b` ie shift `a` right `b` times

Comment: Not able to get it .Please clear it with an example

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre it shifts the number a to right b times .This much i know .I think you are wrong .

Comment: What do you not understand? `a >>= b` is `a = a >> b`

Comment: _@samarthkejriwal_ @Jean is right. What don't you understand specifically?

Comment: @Rakete1111 .Okk got it.I was confused with the assignment operator which was being used there.

Comment: gaurav is saying it shifts right and jean is saying it shifts left.How can both be correct

Comment: @samarthkejriwal Consider that as a _typo_. He's at least right about the division.

Comment: So why is my answered being given unuseful.I couldnt reach the internet for that solution

Comment: @Gaurav >> is right shift and << is left shift.Refer this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm)

Comment: @samarthkejriwal I knew this too.But then this confused me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx The order in the heading , creates confusion

Comment: Why so many downvotes? If a question is off-topic or duplicate, it doesn't mean it deserves downvotes. I think people mix the two concepts.

Comment: @nbro It just decreased my reputation.nothing else.I tried my best to google and find the solution  but couldnt get it so i posted the question here:(

Answer (score 0):

In the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) that you provided, there is a code snippet that uses a compound assignment operator:

`a+=2; // equivalent to a=a+2`

The `>>=` operator also works in a similar way:

`a>>=2; // equivalent to a=a>>2`

`>>` is called as the **(Right) Shift** operator, and shifts the source operand's binary representation to the right by a certain number of bits. For instance, let us have this code snippet:

```
int a=12;
cout<<a<<endl;
a>>=2;
cout<<a<<endl;
```

The output of the code segment, when executed with a C++ compiler will be:

```
12
3
```

What exactly happens is this: `a` has the value of 12, which is represented in binary as (only showing the last 6 bits) 001100. `a>>=2;` shifts the bits in `a` by 2 places to the right and assigns the new value to `a`, hence the new bit positions become 000011, which is 3 in decimal, and hence `a` gets the value of 3, and the resulting output.

Hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: Will the answer be same for `a=13 , a>>=2` and `a=12,a>>=2`??

Comment: Yes, the last two bits get shifted out of the number and hence you get the same answer (i.e. 3). You can think of right shifting by `n` times as doing an integer division of the source operand by 2^n, hence 13/4=12/4=3.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is the right shift operator.

As you mentioned `>>=` is a compound assignment operator. A compound assignment modifies the variable with the operator and assigns the new value to itself.

`a >>= b` is equivalent to `a = a >> b`
i.e., a is right shifted b times and assigned back to a.

For example,

```
int a = 8, b = 2;
a >>= b; // right shift by 2 i.e. divide by 2 x b times.
cout << a; // prints value of 2
```